# how do I in gnome-tweak-tool connects the win/super button to the hyper modifer

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

After updating to Ubuntu 19.04, my keybordlayout no longer works, and I need to reconfigure it.

After trying to use xmodmap, with no result, I tried using gnome-tweak-tool.

Reconfigure the Caps-lock to work as Super was easy:

[image: Caps-lock Settings]

Found a "Hyper is mapped to Win", but after selecting that, the win-button still reacted as a Super.

[image]

Is "Alt/Win" the right place to change this?
Where can I find an explanation to what they relly do?
And how do I make the win-button act as Hyper?

Comment: I just tried y0ur way... my super key became  hyper..

Comment: @PRATAP: how did you varyfy it? I tried to set a shorcut in terminal, but when pressing Win+V it displayed as Super+V

Comment: I verified it by `xev` command after doing the things in gnome-tweaks your way.. `keycode 133 (keysym 0xffed, Hyper_L)` original keycode 133 is Left Super..

Comment: @PRATAP xev prints alot of stuff I don't know, but clicking Capslock sometimes says SUPER_L, and pressing win-button says HYPER_L and alot more. But the keybinding settings still register it as a Super :-(

Comment: I dont know the use of Hyper..I am not able to test it.. how to verify the Hyper key? I am sure.. Tweaks is the rite thing..

Comment: Oh.. Ok.. if you try to make keyboard shortcuts.. It will register the key as unmodified key.. no matter what have you tweaked..

Comment: Seams to be my earlier test with xmodmap + the settings above, that didn't work togheter.

Comment: xmodmap, did you create a text file or just ran the command in terminal like `xmodmap -e "` bring backthe xmodmap to normal and then try..

Comment: By default i have both super and hyper at mod4, with that even if the win-button sends a Hyper, it going to be a mod4, and seen as a Super button.
using `xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Hyper_L" -e "add mod3 = Hyper_L" -e "remove mod4 = Hyper_R" -e "add mod3 = Hyper_R"` to move all hyper to mod3, works in combination with above.

Comment: y0u can write it as answer.. nice explanation fr0m y0u..